# T-SQL Updating Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to figure out how to SUM several columns and update an existing column with 1 or 0 if the SUM of the columns is more than 0.
Also, making sure null values get assigned a 0 value.

How to do something like the following in T-SQL?

```
if (select (coalesce(COL1, 0) +
coalesce(COL2 0) +
coalesce(COL3, 0) +
coalesce(COL4, 0) +
coalesce(COL5, 0) from SOMETABLE where X_CONDITION = 10)  >  0)
update SOMETABLE set ABC_COLUMN = 1
    else
    set ABC_COLUMN = 0;
```

EDIT:

Currently the table looks somewhat like this:

```
x_condition | col1 | col2 |col3| col4| col5| abc_column
------------| -----| -----| ---| ----|-----|-----------
     7      | 1    |      |    |     |     |    0  (this in incorrect)
     7      | 0    |   0  |    |  0  |     |    0  (this is correct)
     5      | 1    |   1  |    |     |     |    0  (this is incorrect)
```

I want the abc_column fixed - almost like a flag:

```
 x_condition | col1 | col2 |col3| col4| col5| abc_column
------------| -----| -----| ---| ----|-----|-----------
     7      | 1    |      |    |     |     |    1
     7      | 0    |   0  |    |  0  |     |    0
     5      | 1    |   1  |    |     |     |    1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired reulsts.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I provided a simple example of what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an `update` statement with some arithmetic:

```
update SOMETABLE
    set ABC_COLUMN = (case when coalesce(COL1, 0) + coalesce(COL2 0) +
                                coalesce(COL3, 0) + coalesce(COL4, 0) +
                                coalesce(COL5, 0) > 0
                           then 1 else 0
                      end);
```

You pretty much have all the pieces in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Use UPDATE statement as below format :

```
  UPDATE SOMETABLE
  SET ABC_COLUMN = CASE WHEN ISNULL(COL1,0) > 0 THEN 1
                        WHEN ISNULL(COL2,0) > 0 THEN 1
                        WHEN ISNULL(COL3,0) > 0 THEN 1
                        WHEN ISNULL(COL4,0) > 0 THEN 1
                        WHEN ISNULL(COL5,0) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```